# Getting an int out of NSConcreteValue / NSValue

Tags: ios, ios5, core-foundation, nsvalue

I am trying to extract an int inside of a `NSValue` / `NSConcreteValue` instance. I tried to cast them this way, but it didn't work:

```
    NSValue *toValue = (NSValue *)someValue;
    NSNumber *toNumber = (NSNumber*)toValue;
    int final = [toNumber intValue];
```

I also tried using `getValue` but that also didn't work for me.

Comment: What is `someValue` originally? Why are you casting it to an `NSValue`? When you say "didn't work," what error are you receiving?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure an int was saved into it? If yes you might get it with:

```
int final = 0;
[someValue getValue:&final];
```

you know you can ask a NSValue its type with

```
[value objCType]
```

which returns a const char *

cheers, Jörg

Comment: I seem to get an `EXEC_BAD_ACCESS` error when I do this, although when I `NSLog` final, I get the correct int value.

Comment: does `int *final; [someValue getValue:final];` work? you would then geht the int by f.e. `NSLog(@"%d",*final)` ...

Comment: and what does `NSLog(@"%s", [value objCType]);` actually print?

Comment: Ok I see what's the problem here, I get a `{CGPoint=ff}` as the result of `objCType`. I'm dealing with an animation and didn't realize the final value would be a CGPoint, not a single number.

Comment: Casting to a `CGPoint` seems to have fixed everything, thanks!